# How to Create ASPX web pages dynamic when the site is run(Like Tag Pages)?

Tags: c#, asp.net, redirect, dynamic, master-pages

I have a site with articles.
each article at the end have several tag keywords.
i want to produce aspx web pages, base on the tag keyword when user click on that
Example:
my page address is :

http://www.nerkhyab.com/pages/default.aspx

now imagine the text inside the page is contained the kewords like {Gold} or {Silver}

i want to when the user click on Gold,it redirect to a page**(The page doesn't exists before)** like this :

http://www.nerkhyab.com/pages/Gold.aspx

So how can i create a page in aspx(which not exists) and redirect to that page?

Attention: The GOLD page most use a Master Page
http://www.nerkhyab.com/default.aspx

Comment: Check out these links http://forums.asp.net/t/1830236.aspx  and http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/189438/How-to-create-Asp-NET-aspx-Page-at-Runtime

Answer (score 0):

Suppose:

Table - Article : I am considering only few columns with their datatypes that relates to an article.

```
Id (PK, Autogenerated),  Title(varchar(1000)), 
Description(ntext), ArticleDate(datetime2), Tags(varchar(1000))
```

Allow user to select multiple tags as SO does or a text box where tags will be entered as comma separated value.

Suppose after entering a record we have

```
Id | Title                      | Description     | ArticleDate | Tags
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
1 | How to use tags in article? | blah!blah!blah! | 09/07/2013 | c#,asp.net,
                                                                 English,.net, 
                                                                 sql
```

say front end has link having tag `SQL`. When a user clicks on Sql redirect it like something

`http://domain:port/some_dir/article.aspx?tag=sql`

Now on your Article.Aspx Page Load event, check `if(Request.Querystring["tag"]!=null)`
then extract the tag passed using `var tag = Request.QueryString["tag"]` and query it with your table.

Query:

`Select * From Table where Tag like '%sql%'  //here sql will be passed dynamically so it may be different as i have mentioned.`

Comment: :O this is not really useful for me

Comment: i want to know how to generate the page.NOT how to query from my data base for tags